# Thread issues when writing to files with OpenMP in Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp

The number of files that are getting written is always less than the number of threads. Logically for me, when I can have 4 threads and the CPU is working at 400%, I was expecting the number of files to be 4 (one each corresponding to every single thread). I don't know if there is a problem with my code or this is how it is supposed to work. The code is as follows:

```
     !!!!!!!! module 
      module common
      use iso_fortran_env
      implicit none
      integer,parameter:: dp=real64
      real(dp):: aa,bb

       contains

      subroutine evolve(y,yevl)
      implicit none
      integer(dp),parameter:: id=2
      real(dp),intent(in):: y(id)
      real(dp),intent(out):: yevl(id)
        yevl(1)=y(2)+1.d0-aa*y(1)**2
        yevl(2)=bb*y(1)
      end subroutine evolve

      end module common

      use common
      implicit none
      integer(dp):: iii,iter,i
      integer(dp),parameter:: id=2
      real(dp),allocatable:: y(:),yt(:)
      integer(dp):: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM, IXD

       allocate(y(id)); allocate(yt(id)); y=0.d0; yt=0.d0; bb=0.3d0
       !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(iii,iter,y,i,yt) SHARED(bb)
         IXD=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
       !$OMP DO
        do iii=1,20000; print*,iii  !! EXPECTED THREADS TO BE OF 5000 ITERATIONS EACH
          aa=1.d0+dfloat(iii-1)*0.4d0/80000.d0
            loop1: do iter=1,10 !! THE INITIAL CONDITION LOOP
               call random_number(y)!! RANDOM INITIALIZATION OF THE VARIABLE
                loop2: do i=1,70000  !! ITERATION OF THE SYSTEM
                    call evolve(y,yt)
                    y=yt
                enddo loop2     !! END OF SYSTEM ITERATION
              write(IXD+1,*)aa,yt  !!! WRITING FILE CORRESPONDING TO EACH THREAD
            enddo loop1 !!INITIAL CONDITION ITERATION DONE
         enddo
        !$OMP ENDDO
        !$OMP END PARALLEL
        end
```

Is this behavior resulting from some race issue in the code? The code compiles and executes just fine without any warnings or errors with ifort version 13.1.0 on ubuntu. Thanks a bunch for any comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `IXD` should be explicitely declared as private to make sure every thread has an own copy of it. Changing the line(s)

```
   !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(iii,iter,y,i,yt) SHARED(bb)
   IXD=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
```

to

```
  !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(iii,iter,y,i,yt,ixd) SHARED(bb)
  IXD=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
```

solves the problem.

Comment: yes indeed, it did the job. Thank you so much for the quick insight. Works perfectly. I was thinking of some race issues but this did the job.